# Turn Surface pen on and touch off

Tags: touchscreen, microsoft-surface, microsoft-surface-pro-3

When using a pen on the Surface or similar computer, resting the hand on the screen can trigger unwanted actions. How can the hand-touch function be disabled while allowing pen functions to continue to work?

Answer (score 1):

The MS `Surface Pro` has two different technologies built into its display.

The first is what we all commonly use on smartphones and other touch screen devices, is a capacitive touch screen, these work by measuring disturbances in the electrical field on the glass touchscreen.

The second technology in the `Pro 3` is the pen which is based off of the wireless field technology developed by N-Trig (a Microsoft company), or Wacom in the `Pro` / `Pro 2`; this one works by measuring disturbances in a wireless electric field above the display.

On the Surface, like the Galaxy Note, when the pen is within range of the wireless field, it simply ignores the input of the capacitive touch panel, and only commands windows with the input from the wireless field.

On non pro models that do not have pen support, there is no way to distinguish a difference.

Answer (score -3):

You're kidding. There's no way the screen can distinguish hand from pen; it just reacts to electromagnetic energy. It can't know what's touching it and whether you wanted that to be it or not.

Re-adjusting the way you use it would be the best bet. What you want is theoretically possible though.

Another method is leaning your hand firstly atop the screen, and not re-releasing it as you write; or put something on your hand that is non-conductive so that it won't conduct any energy when you're on it.

Comment: This is quite wrong.  I've used multiple touch/pen systems that react differently to touch vs. pen as the system can tell them apart.